# Angular2 iframe video " unsafe value used in a resource URL"

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to use iframe vimeo video in my website, but I keep getting:

> unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

I know this question been asked before by people and I looked in the official documentation and using DomSanitizer, but I still get an error.

I have created simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btluxf?file=src/app/app.component.html) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

change your iframe src to `[src]="url"`

and your constructor to

```
this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://player.vimeo.com/video/276885072");
  }
```